# User function doesn't work after being copied to a new cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following function to sum a range of cells based on the cell color.

```
Function SumByColor(CellColor As Range, R As Range)

Dim x As Double: x = 0
Dim i As Long: i = CellColor.Interior.Color
For Each Item In R
    If Item.Interior.Color = i Then x = x + Item.Value
    Next Item
SumByColor = x

End Function
```

When I first use it, it works fine.  However, when I copy/paste it to a 2nd cell, the result is the original value - makes sense because I use the cell that I want the result to go into as the 1st argument to the function call, and it gets changed with the copy/paste.  But then, I change the cell color and the result doesn't change the way I expect it to.

1st function call:

```
=sumbycolor(J5,$E$1:$E$58)
```

The function is in cell J5, which is green and the result is xxxx

Copy/pasted function call:

```
=sumbycolor(J8,$E$1:$E$58)
```

The function is in cell J8, which became green with the copy/paste and the result is xxxx

Then I changed the color of cell J8 to blue, which should have changed the result from xxxx to yyyy - but it didn't.

Manually recalculating the worksheet did not work, and neither did saving the workbook, closing it and reopening it.  Typing the function call into a new (blue) cell gives the proper result of yyyy.  Changing the color of the cell in the original cell also doesn't cause the result to change as expected.

It also doesn't work if I use a different cell to get the color code - ie using the color in cell J8 and the function call in K8.  It gets the correct sum the 1st time, but doesn't update if I then change the color in J8.

When I say "change the color of the cell" I'm using the drop down menu to change it - not a formula or function. It looks like the Color property of the cell doesn't get updated when I do this - is there something else I need to do in the function to make sure it recalculates with the current Color setting?

Comment: Press F2 to edit the formula, press enter. It recalculated for me in Excel 2010.  This happens in other cases in excel as well... regarding the generation of hyperlinks and automatic number detection. Also as soon as you change any of the data it updates as well...

Comment: I'm almost sure that there is no way to make changing colors call a user defined function. F2 can be translate to code: 'Range("A1:A10").formula = Range("A1:A10").formula' > assuming you have the formula in A1:A10. This updates the udf values.